# Android - checkable buttons on options menu

Tags: android, button, options-menu

Can anyone point in the direction of any tutorials that show how to create an options menu with clicakble checks like in the picture below:

---

[alt text http://img291.imageshack.us/img291/1221/deviceit.png](http://img291.imageshack.us/img291/1221/deviceit.png)

---

I have tried as follows:

```
/** Menu creation and setup **/

/* Creates the menu items */
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
 boolean result = super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    menu.add(0, 1, 0, "Speaker").setCheckable(true);
    menu.add(0, 2, 0, "Mute").setCheckable(true);
    return result;
}

/* Handles item selections */
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case 1:
  if(audioManager.isSpeakerphoneOn()==false){
   audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
   audioManager.setRouting(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL,
      AudioManager.ROUTE_SPEAKER, AudioManager.ROUTE_ALL);
  }else{
   audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);
   audioManager.setRouting(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL,
      AudioManager.ROUTE_EARPIECE, AudioManager.ROUTE_ALL);
  }
        return true;
    case 2:
     if(audioManager.isMicrophoneMute())
   audioManager.setMicrophoneMute(false);
   else
   audioManager.setMicrophoneMute(true);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

---

But this doesn't work it only gives me text on the buttons on the options menu

**EDIT: I have added the following onPrepareOptionsMenu method:**

```
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    boolean result = super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);

    if(audioManager.isSpeakerphoneOn())
     menu.findItem(1).setChecked(true);
    else
     menu.findItem(1).setChecked(false);

    if(audioManager.isMicrophoneMute())
     menu.findItem(2).setChecked(true);
    else
     menu.findItem(2).setChecked(false);


    return result;
}
```

---

However I get the same outcome just text and no check light as in the picture above

Comment: Old question, but just a note to anyone looking - when using menu.findItem() use the item id rather than a index number. i.e. menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to change dynamically the state of your Option Menu, you need to use `onPrepareMenu()`. In this method, you can do dynamic checks and update anything you want. 
Good luck!!
[documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPrepareOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu%29)

After some digging, this look like a custom view. I think your picture comes [from this code](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Phone.git;a=blob;f=src/com/android/phone/InCallMenuView.java;h=560a082b6da4dd9879912ca7fe4e917682c80600;hb=HEAD).

Comment: I have added that method, I have edited my question to show you my code, but the outcome is the same, I cant get it to produce the check light that turns on and off (The green one)

Comment: Actually, the image you are displaying looks like a custom view... Is it something you found on the web? Cause maybe this is it not possible directly from the basic API and you'd have to build your own menu. I don't remember ever seeing a menu in android with the icon below the text.

Comment: Its standard from Android 1.6, Vanilla as in its pure Android 1.6, not a custom ROM

Comment: Did you look at the link I added in my edit? I think the code could be what you need.

Comment: This isn't an API function. It's manually changing the drawable for the options button. Options buttons can't be checkboxes

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but I had the same problem and searched a lot to find such an optionsMenu shown above. I found a tutorial on http://www.codeproject.com and modified it a little bit. Maybe it is not a profi-programmers-code, but it works for me. See my modifications at my (poor arranged) web page on google sites (I got an little tutorial too on this site):

https://sites.google.com/site/opiatefuchs/android-code-examples

This code is original from wjfrancis on the Code Project web page (many props):

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/173121/Android-Menus-My-Way

I just modified it and would be glad if somebody got any ideas to improve this code. But for now, it works.